# Compare data from RecyclerView with Realtime Database in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm making a Quizz app  and I have the questions and the answers in Realtime Database,
I have no problem displaying the information in the recyclerview, this recycler view is composed of a radio group of 3 radio buttons,
I need to compare the radio button with the record of the correct answer in realtime database.

[image: This is the structure of the database]

```
 btnacab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    if(corregido == false){

                        //for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                            int cont = 1;
                            String p = "p";
                            npreg = p + cont;

                            corregirpregunta("Enfermeria", "p1");
                            corregido = true;
                            btnacab.setText("SALIR");

                            cont++;
                       // }

                    }else{
                        Intent i = new Intent(ModeloExamen3.this, GeneralTest.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });

            pauseTimer();
        }
    });
    */
}

public void corregirpregunta(String tipo, String npreg){

    database.child(tipo).child(npreg).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            PreguntaExamen pregunta = snapshot.getValue(PreguntaExamen.class);

            if(pregunta != null){
                String corr = pregunta.getCorrecta();
                int n = Integer.parseInt(corr.toString());
                RadioButton rbselected = findViewById(rgrex.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                int nresp = rgrex.indexOfChild(rbselected) +1 ;

                if(nresp == n){
                    puntuacion++;
                    tvpuntu.setText("Puntuación: " + puntuacion+"/10");
                }
                resp1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                resp2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                resp3.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                switch (n){

                    case 1:
                        resp1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        resp2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        resp3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

The method to correct a single question works well, the problem is to make a loop so that a single method corrects all the questions that are shown in the recyclerview.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: The method corregirpregunta() works fine for only 1 question but I want to use it in a loop to correct all the questions in the recyclerview. .In the onClick method I tried to get the information out of the firebase with the loop that is commented but it doesn't work, thats the problem

Comment: To understand better, you need to get all children that exist under `A2/Enfermedia/General`, right?

Comment: I need to get the "correcta" variable from firebase and then compare it with the the checked radiobutton from the recycler